# I want to increase blogger number of posts displayed in search page. (not label page)

Tags: blogger

I want to increase number of results in one page of blogger for `/search?submit=&q=` format. There are many posts to increase results for label page but I can't find for search result page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your search form an input like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='max-results' value='3'/>
```

Modify the `value` attribute for set the maximum number of results per page.